# Hyperlinked URLs are redirecting to some suspicious webpages

Tags: wordpress

Google search console has detected some suspicious urls on my website. If I copy and paste those URLs on the browser, it shows 404 error. But If I hyperlinked those URLs and clicked, it redirected to some Japanese websites.
Here is one example
https://www.campion.edu.au/23026iieoc598b24we4a8e4a68 (Copy and paste it on a browser, you will see 404 error)
https://www.campion.edu.au/23026iieoc598b24we4a8e4a68Click the hyperlinked version, you will see a different website

Answer (score 0):

Few Solutions are:

1. check index.php and wp-config.php for malicious code.
2. replace wordpress with latest wordpress files except wp-content folder
3. check if .htaccess is generated in sub directories, if yes then delete them all
4. check the redirection url in database using mysql query and remove the code if added somewhere.
5. deactivate all plugins to debug website and enable WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php file.

Let me know if any point works for you?